# Highcharts export: Unable to export rendered arc colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using a polar chart with chart type line and rendering colors into it once chart gets created.

On exporting chart as a png, svg etc the colors which are rendered doesn't appear in exported chart.

Is there a way to retain rendered colors on exported chart?

```js
$(function () {
    
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
     chart: {
         polar: true,
            renderTo: 'container'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
     },
     pane: {
         startAngle: 0,
         endAngle: 360
     },
     xAxis: {
         tickInterval: 45,
         min: 0,
         max: 360,
         labels: {
          formatter: function () {
           return this.value + '°';
          }
         }
     },
     yAxis: {
         min: 0,
          tickInterval: 2,
          showLastLabel: true
     },
     plotOptions: {
         series: {
             pointStart: 0,
             pointInterval: 45
         },
         column: {
             pointPadding: 0,
             groupPadding: 0
         },
          line: {
            pointPlacement: "between",
              dataLabels: {
                  allowOverlap: true,
                  enabled: true
              }
          }
     },
     series: [{
         type: 'line',
         name: 'Line',
         data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
     }]
 });
    
    var colors = ["#058DC7", "#50B432", "#ED561B", "#DDDF00", "#24CBE5", "#7cb5ec", "#434348", "#90ed7d", "#f7a35c", "#8085e9", "#f15c80", "#e4d354", "#2b908f", "#f45b5b", "#91e8e1", "#696969", "#64E572", "#FF9655", "#FFF263", "#6AF9C4"];    
    var parts = 8;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
        chart.renderer.arc(chart.plotLeft + chart.yAxis[0].center[0], 
                           chart.plotTop + chart.yAxis[0].center[1], 
                           chart.yAxis[0].height, 
                           0, 
                           -Math.PI + (Math.PI/(parts/2) * i), 
                           -Math.PI + (Math.PI/(parts/2) * (i+1))).attr({
            fill: colors[i % colors.length],
            'stroke-width': 1,
            'opacity': 1
        }).add();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Refer to this http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defaulty when you export chart, then new copy of options are exported, ignoring elementes which are renderered after chart init. Like your arcs. You should add shapes in load event to keep that objects "in chart options".

```
chart: {
  polar: true,
  renderTo: 'container',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this,
        parts = 8,
        colors = ["#058DC7", "#50B432", "#ED561B", "#DDDF00", "#24CBE5", "#7cb5ec", "#434348", "#90ed7d", "#f7a35c", "#8085e9", "#f15c80", "#e4d354", "#2b908f", "#f45b5b", "#91e8e1", "#696969", "#64E572", "#FF9655", "#FFF263", "#6AF9C4"];

      for (var i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
        chart.renderer.arc(chart.plotLeft + chart.yAxis[0].center[0],
          chart.plotTop + chart.yAxis[0].center[1],
          chart.yAxis[0].height,
          0, -Math.PI + (Math.PI / (parts / 2) * i), -Math.PI + (Math.PI / (parts / 2) * (i + 1))).attr({
          fill: colors[i % colors.length],
          'stroke-width': 1,
          'opacity': 1
        }).add();
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/71yrh58e/1/